# Code only works when PDB is active

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pdb

I am currently trying to create a main window that can interact with a dialog window, but I came across an issue I thought was interesting.

Basically, I'm trying to get `test_1` to interact with `test_2`. When I test the code by itself, works, and does what it's supposed to do, but when I use `Test_1` to interact with `Test_2`, the script regarding test 2 no longer has its full functionality.

Interestingly enough, when I go through the code, it's able to print `"hello"`, and the function that I link to `print("hello")` isn't tied to a class. However, the function that doesn't work (the function where I just ask to insert "hello" into a text box) is tied to a class and that is the function that is not working. Also, the code works just fine if I use `pdb` within the `Test_1`.

Here is my code regarding test 1 and test 2 (you'll probably have to install PyQT5 if you haven't already):

Test_1

```
import test_2 as t2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Test_1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test_1):
        Test_1.setObjectName("Test_1")
        Test_1.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test_1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 120, 461, 281))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        Test_1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Test_1)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Test_1.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Test_1)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Test_1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Test_1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test_1)


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.connect_test_2)



    def retranslateUi(self, Test_1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Test_1.setWindowTitle(_translate("Test_1", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Test_1", "Open Dialog"))

    def connect_test_2(self):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        self.t2 = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = t2.Ui_Test_2()
        ui.setupUi(self.t2)
        self.t2.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Test_1()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Test 2

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Test_2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test_2):
        Test_2.setObjectName("Test_2")
        Test_2.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Test_2)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 20, 81, 241))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Test_2)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 90, 341, 161))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Test_2)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 104, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Test_2)

        #self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Test_2.accept)
        #self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Test_2.reject)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test_2)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.printHello)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(dummyCode)


    def printHello(self):
        self.textEdit.setText("Hello")


    def retranslateUi(self, Test_2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Test_2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Test_2", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Test_2", "PushButton"))

def dummyCode():
    print("Hello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Test_2()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```